# Formal way of saying "cutting"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

Say there is a very long article, I took it, then *cut/shrink/excerpt* it to a much shorter version.

What the proper way to express the meaning/action of  ***cut/shrink/excerpt***, but in a respectful way?

Comment: In what context? Without knowing what you're talking about, there's no indication that *cutting* is disrespectful in the first place. (In fact, I can't think of a context where it *would* be disrespectful.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, _"I took the article from Wikipedia then **cut** it into the above shorter version"_ I know _cut_ might sound perfectly fine to you but I just don't feel like to use it this way. Maybe the term "respectful"/"disrespectful" is a bit too hmm..., what's the word here, strong, but _"cut"_ implies _"something wrong"_ to me, at least being too spoken-language, I want to express in written-language, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for "formal" rather than "respectful"?

Comment: Good point @Deolater, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Abridge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abridge) is a very formal word for this:

> to shorten by omission of words without sacrifice of sense

However, in most contexts, I would prefer *condense,* which the linked definition lists as a synonym of *abridge.* *Abridge* is more of technical term used in the publishing industry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Max! That exactly answers what I'm asking for. However, I do normally wait for several days (for the community input) before making my selection. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Max, could you expand on your saying _"I'm partial to condense"_. I don't quite understand what you were trying to say, and looked it up and found one meaning of ***partial*** is _"favoring one side in a dispute above the other; biased"_. Is that what you were trying to express? Please elaborate.

Comment: I prefer "condense" because "abridge" seems *too*  formal for most contexts. You'll see some books advertised as "abridged editions," but at work I would more likely ask someone to "condense" or "cut down" a long document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaboration, Max, and welcome to ell.stackexchange with my +25. BTW, if you can update your answer with your new input, that'd be better, which is the norm of what people are doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The verb I would use in a conversation or email is simply to *shorten* the article. "Shorten" is a general verb, not specific to text, but it would be perfectly correct and understood from the context.

The verb *abridge* is specific to shortening text, but you would find it more commonly used as a base of the adjective "abridged" (and sometimes "unabridged") than as a verb in the active voice (see [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abridge%2Cabridged%2Cunabridged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabridge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabridged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunabridged%3B%2Cc0)). It is indeed quite formal as noted in Max's answer.

You can find some other words that can be used based on these words in a [thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/abridge).

Comment: The reason I didn't list "_shorten_" in my OP is because it doesn't play well as drop-in replacement with phrases like _"cut it short"_, or _"cut to a shorter version"_ to me. Anyhow, Thanks for the explanation on "_abridge_" and all.  Upvoting!

Answer (score 0):

A synopsis or a summary are proper, respectful words describing a shorter version of a long text.

Comment: Thanks for the input, by _"cutting"_, I did mean _"cut shorter"_ (70~80% remains), not summarizing (only 10~20% remains, and in my own words too).

Answer (score 0):

From a clarifying comment under the question:

> "I took the article from Wikipedia then **cut** it into the above shorter version."

If you are taking a long piece of text and reducing to a smaller number of key points, I would say that you are **summarizing** it.

From [*summarize*:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summarize)

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to tell in or reduce to a summary
>   // I would like to take a moment to *summarize* the facts that I presented earlier.
>   // He *summarized* by saying we needed better planning and implementation.

And from [*summary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summary):

> *adjective*
>   **1** : COMPREHENSIVE
>   especially : covering the main points succinctly
>
> *noun*
>   : an abstract, abridgment, or compendium especially of a preceding discourse

Comment: Thanks for the input, by _"cutting"_, I did mean _"cut shorter"_ (70~80% remains), not summarizing (only 10~20% remains, and in my own words too).